# Removing an AdBannerView from a UIViewController from an IAP without having to restart the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsnotification, adbannerview

I have a 5-tab `UITabBarController` where each Tab is a `UIViewController`. The first tab is called `Timeline`, the second is called `Person` and the last tab is called `More`.

I have implemented `In-App Purchase`s with my app where before the `IAP`, the user cannot for example change themes, etc. One of the things I am bringing to this version is removing `iAds` with the `IAP`.

So the `Timeline` has an `AdBannerView` at the bottom before the `IAP` has been made, and as soon as the `IAP` has been purchased from the `More` tab, I'm expecting the `AdBannerView` to be removed from the `Timeline` straight away.

**Issue**

What's actually happening now is I go to the `More` tab, purchase the `IAP` and go back to the `Timeline` and the `AdBannerView` is still there. If I move from the `Timeline` tab to the `Person` tab and back to the `Timeline` tab, the `AdBannerView` is removed. Or, if I relaunch the app after the `IAP`, the `AdBannerView` is removed from the `Timeline`. Either way, it's not doing what I expect, which is to remove the `AdBannerView` the first time I go back to the `Timeline` tab from the `More` tab, after the `IAP`.

Here's some code:

```
- (void)displayiAdsOrNot
{
    NSLog(@"Display iAds or Not");
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"IAPSuccessful"])
    {
        NSLog(@"BASIC");

        self.adBanner = [[self appdelegate] adBanners];
        self.adBanner.delegate = self;

        if (IDIOM == IPAD)
        {
            NSLog(@"*** This is the iPad ***");
            [self.adBanner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-80, 320, 50)];
            [self.adBanner setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

            [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
            NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                               constraintWithItem:self.adBanner
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                               toItem:self.view
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                               multiplier:1.0
                                               constant:0];

            [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];



            myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.adBanner
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                      multiplier:1
                                                        constant:0];

            [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];

            myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.adBanner
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      multiplier:1
                                                        constant:0];

            [self.view addConstraint:myConstraint];

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"*** THIS IS THE IPHONE ***");
            [self.adBanner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-98, 320, 50)];
            [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"PRO");
        [self.adBanner removeFromSuperview];
        self.adBanner = nil;
    }   
}
```

This method is called only from the `viewWillAppear`.

With the `NSLogs` as a guide, in the `Timeline` tab, the console displays `BASIC`. When I go to the `More` tab, purchase the `IAP` and back to the `Timeline` tab, the `viewWillAppear` fires off again which fires off the `displayiAdsOrNot` method and this time, I get the `NSLog` `PRO` because the `NSUserDefault` `IAPSuccessful` is now true (which is done when the purchase goes through).

However, at this point, the `AdBannerView` is still displayed.

**What I've tried**

I've been trying a number of things to try get this working:

- Create a `NSNotification` when the purchase goes through, with a listener in the `viewWillAppear` method of the `Timeline` tab. In that method, set `self.adBanner` to `nil`, remove it from the superview, etc. The selector gets fired off with the `Notification` (before the `viewWillAppear`), but nothing different happens.
- I've tried `self.adBanner.delegate = self; self.adBanner = nil; [self.adBanner removeFromSuperview];` etc and it's the same
- I've tried `[self.timelineTableView reloadData];`
- Following this similar SO question ([Reloading an SKScene or View to remove iAd after In App Purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862910/reloading-an-skscene-or-view-to-remove-iad-after-in-app-purchase)), I've even tried setting the ivar to no effect.
- I've tried placing the `self.adBanner` to off the screen, but the same thing is happening; when the Timeline is loaded, the `AdBannerView` is still there until I go somewhere else.

I have the `viewWillDisappear` as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.adBanner.delegate = nil;
    self.adBanner=nil;
    [self.adBanner removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This is for the purpose of using the Shared `AdBannerViews`. The `self.adBanner` is a property created in the .h file and I'm using `@synthesize adBanner = _adBanner` in the .m file.

Any guidance on this would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue.

By removing the `viewWillDisappear` and setting the `self.adBanner.hidden` `= YES` if the `IAPSuccessful` and in the `Notification`, I've managed to get rid of the `AdBannerView` without restarting the app.